# Каким членом предложения является словосочетание "два года"?

Tags: члены-предложения

Каким членом предложения является словосочетание «два года» в следующем предложении?

> Я готовился к экзаменам два года.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем примере *два года* является обстоятельством времени, зависит от сказуемого *готовился* и отвечает на вопрос *как долго?*